# Meet a friend while in transit at the airport?

Tags: visas, transit, airports, transit-visas, layovers

I live in France. As part of a long multi-part flight, a friend of mine will be spending a night at the Charles de Gaulle Airport (in Paris, France), without a Schengen Visa (he has only the transit Visa). Therefore he cannot leave the "International zone" of the airport.

Is there any way I could meet with him in the Airport? Perhaps a VIP saloon, or a hotel in the international zone? I could even consider buying a cheap flight ticket (that I probably wouldn't take), just to be able to enter the airport, if that's the only option.

Thanks.

Comment: We have a question about a like situation in Heathrow airport, which I can not find now, where the answers all indicated that buying a ticket out of the same terminal was the only or at least by far the best option. I am not familiar enough with CDG airport to answer this question but it is likely that the same restrictions apply.

Comment: Be aware that in some situations, passengers in transit with certain nationalities/arriving from specific countries (and I would think that correlates strongly with people requiring an ATV) are met right at the aircraft door, escorted to an isolated area which they can’t leave, and then escorted to the onward flight. In that situation you are unlikely to be able to see them at all. Not sure exactly in which circumstances this happens, though (or whether that still happens).

Comment: @jcaron I don't think this applies in current situation. My friend has transited previous through Paris, with an ATV. He just stays in some waiting area or a hotel inside CDG.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, I'm considering buying a cheap ticket. Please post the link if you do find it.

Comment: @a06e [Can i meet a friend at LHR while i am in a Transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177917/can-i-meet-a-friend-at-lhr-while-i-am-in-a-transit)

Comment: @a06e where is your friend arriving from/departing to, on which airline(s)? Most airside terminal areas are only accessible to passengers on flights using that specific gate area. While for some flights the gate area is well known in advance, for others it may vary (especially for flights to/from 2E, where there are separate concourses K, L and M). The only common part in there is around the people mover between the concourses), I’m not even sure there is a place you could sit down. Also “cheap” flight usually means non-flexible, so non-refundable.

Comment: This is the question I was thinking of, although the one found by @BernhardDöbler has good information as well: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179529/skip-heathrow-flight-after-passing-security?rq=1